# How to pass image path as an array in JavaScript function in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<script>
var myBgFader = $('.header').bgfader([
  'images/banner1-1.jpg',
  'images/banner1-2.jpg',
  'images/banner1-3.jpg',
  'images/banner1-4.jpg',
], {
  'timeout': 2000,
  'speed': 3000,
  'opacity': 0.4
})

myBgFader.start()
</script>
```

In bgfader array I need to give image path. I tried with normal as shown above, but image is not displaying.

How should I give image to this?

Comment: what you exactly want to do here ? want to pass images as array or yor array is  working fine but want to put full path including http ? please confirm.

Comment: I need to pass path to image, mentioned path is not displaying any images

Comment: so you mean you want to add full path like this **http://www.example.com/images/banner1.jpg** ?

Comment: ya somewhat.. just need to display image

Comment: simple .. if u have a theme ..  create javascript in header and define variable something like this `var baseurl = <?php your wordpress function which has an ability to give website url;' . then you need to append this variable here in your js code hope it makes sense.

Comment: but you cant use php in JS right ?

Comment: who says ? u can ..

Comment: let me try then..

Comment: sample `alert("<?php echo "asdasda";?>");`

Comment: but how to pass this in to array?

Comment: `var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';` alert this variable.

Comment: var baseurl_1 = '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/banner1-1.jpg'; not working

Comment: boss .. can you just `alert(templateUrl )` ?

Comment: i did that getting undefined

Comment: did you assign this `var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';` ?

Comment: yup...its showing full path but still image is not showing

Comment: now you need to do something like this https://paste.ee/r/R8KfE

Comment: now you have a full path in your javascript .. you can adjust it based on the http path and folder you have .. hope it makes sense ..

Comment: got it.... was passing path 'like this', but forgot to pass like ([
  templateUrl,
  templateUrl_2,
  templateUrl_3,
  templateUrl_4,
]

Comment: cool :) .. (y) hope you understood the stuff and logic ..

Comment: hahaha ya thnx mate :)

Comment: welcome :) #soreadytohelp

Comment: (y)..............

Comment: are you sure you're not looking for `/images/xxx.jpg` (with a leading `/`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended that you move any custom JS code into it's own JS file and use wp_enqueue_script to enqueue the JS file

Assuming you are properly enqueuing your JS file using the [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function, always use the [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function to pass any server side data to your JS files.

In your WordPress file (either Theme or a plugin file depending on your requirement) use the below code

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_enqueue_scripts' );

function my_custom_enqueue_scripts() {

    // Enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

    // Localize the script with some data
    $some_data = array(
        'template_url' => get_bloginfo("template_url")
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $some_data );
}
```

Then in your JS file you can access the URL like below

```
var myBgFader = $('.header').bgfader([
object_name.template_url + 'images/banner1-1.jpg',
object_name.template_url + 'images/banner1-2.jpg',
object_name.template_url + 'images/banner1-3.jpg',
object_name.template_url + 'images/banner1-4.jpg',
], {
  'timeout': 2000,
  'speed': 3000,
  'opacity': 0.4
})

myBgFader.start()
```

Comment: You ommit to tell that the enqueue functions need to be wrap into a function that will be trigger with wp_enqueue_scripts action.

Comment: Added the function to trigger with wp_enqueue_scripts action

Comment: I think It's better to wp_register_script first, localize and wp_enqueue_script('some_handle'); at the end

Comment: wp_localize_script should be called only after either wp_register_script or wp_enqueue_script so that it hooks properly to the correct script. wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script both functions have their own use cases, but for this OP question, i don't think that matters.

Comment: I say this about the main example https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it using wp_register_script, my answer is the way to do it using only wp_enqueue_script. Both are correct, i responded only to say that both the functions have their own use cases and it really comes down to the particular use case and also the user preference. I personally never had any use case for wp_register_script and always used wp_enqueue_script :)